# Segue desde un view controller dentro de un tab bar a un table view controller externo

Tags: swift, swift4

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Tengo un tab bar view controller con 4 items, cada uno de ellos es un view controller.

El problema es que cuando quiero hacer un segue de uno de esos view controller a un table view controller externo, la vista se me queda dentro del tab bar controller.

¿Como puedo hacer para que no pase eso?
¿Algún segue especial?

Answer (score 0):

Claro, el tabbar controller es un controlador contenedor de esos 4 viewcontrollers que tienes. Si quieres pasar de uno a otro, es el tabBarController quien se ocupa de mostrar uno y quitar el otro. Así pues si en uno de ellos quieres mostrar otro viewcontroller que dependa de ese, pues seguirá estando dentro del tabBarController, ya que el viewcontroller que llama, esta en ese tabBarController.
Lo que tienes que hacer es cuando muestres ese nuevo viewcontroller decirle que desaparezca el tabBarController y cuando vuelvas de ese viewcontroller tienes que decirle que tiene que volver ha aparecer. Así pues en el nuevo viewController que quieres que aparezca deberías poner

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

en el viewDidLoad, en el viewWillAppear como mejor te venga y cuando el viewController se vaya a cerrar pues

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```